# Center Navbar in Twitter Bootstrap 2.0

Tags: css, navigation, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, centering

Suppose we have the following markup for navigation bar using Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner pull-center">
      <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>                        
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>        
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to center `.nav` inside `navbar-inner`?

I only came up with adding my own CSS styles:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
    .pull-center {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .pull-center > .nav {
        float:none;
        display:inline-block;
        *display: inline; *zoom: 1;
        height: 32px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Align how? You mean center inside the `span12` div?

Comment: Are you using the responsive bootstrap stylesheet?

Comment: By the, just tested your css and it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Override the width of the container within the navbar from `auto` to `960px`.

```
.navbar-inner .container {width:960px;}
```

Comment: Hi, this helped me for a standard viewport, but what if I want a responsive version?

Comment: I think you want the variable $gridRowWidth. That is the sass variable at least.

Answer (score 4):

To align it in the center with a dynamic width, I used the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      ....
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar .navbar-inner {
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner .nav {
    float: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Didn't test it, but I guess only `display:inline-block;` could be a problem, which is supported in all browsers except for IE7 and lower..

http://caniuse.com/inline-block

Comment: Additionally you could style .nav-collapse the same as .nav above for responsive navigations

Comment: To overwrite the .nav sometimes it is needed to specify it as `.navbar .nav` not only `.nav`

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using the container class as per http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar is centering my nav; however, it is fixed width and the formatting is off (the height of the nav bar is increased and its very possible something I'm doing wrong).

It would be nice to have the nav centered in a fluid, percentage-based width, with a minimum width, based on some minimum supported device screen size, and nowrap.  (I'm a newbie wrt the responsive media queries and perhaps that is the better alternative to percentage based.)

Still investigating the minimum width and nowrap, but another alternative to the bootstrap container class fixed width is to add a child of the navbar-inner.  I would like to know if there is a built-in bootstrap solution such as the row-fluid and spanN classes, but I haven't been able to get that formatted correctly within the nav either.

```
<div style="margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 15%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this useful and clean:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>                        
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>        
  </div>
</div>
```

where, css is:

```
.container {left:auto;right:auto}
```

This will center the div on the base of the width of your current navbar.

Responsiveness is managed apart.

Comment: browsers latest versions indeed. what's the problem with -1?