# Center Bootstrap Navbar While Preserving Style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How can I center the navbar on [this page](http://qualitypainting.ca/), while still keeping the background gradient? [I've seen some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128812/center-navbar-in-twitter-bootstrap-2-0) where the `li` is set to display `inline`, the `a` to display `inline-block`, and the `ul` to align the text in the center, but these require me to add `float:none` to the code, which breaks my background gradient. Could someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two classes in markup (with optional names, just to override CSS). Lets call it `.nav-container` and `.menu-nav`.

```
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container nav-container">
          <ul class="nav menu-nav">
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and then add in CSS

```
.nav-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-nav {
    float: none;
}
```

I've changed that in my Chrome inspector, and background gradient looks same as before that.

Comment: thank you very much. I think where I went wrong was I didn't create separate classes like you did.