# Centering fixed top navbar for large screens in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I have a fixed top navbar in Twitter Bootstrap 3.
Everything works good until 1350px. After 1350px there becomes a gap between navbar contents. So I want to center my navbar.

I checked answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939481/center-the-nav-in-twitter-bootstrap), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568103/modify-twitter-bootstrap-navbar) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128812/center-navbar-in-twitter-bootstrap-2-0). None of them worked for me.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcqHE/56/
Currently I use `Navbar 1`.
To try centering navbar, I added `Navbar 2` to the fiddle.

Check fiddle in 1500px width.
* Navbar 1 is one line, not centered and has gap.
* Navbar 2 is centered, no gap, but it is two lined.
It seems like the cause is this rule: `@media (min-width: 1200px) .container { max-width: 1170px; }`

So how can I make navbar centered, and one line if width is bigger than 1350px ?

Comment: could you please remove all those inline styles and write separate CSS? (it's a bit a mess like this to see what you've got)

Comment: @caramba I removed inline styles and updated fiddle.

Comment: "something1" and "something2" has also to be centered or always to be same line but on the right side of screen?

Answer (score 3):

This is an aswer for your problem:-)

You need to add follow lines to css:

```
@media screen and (min-width:  1350px) {
   .navbar { text-align: center; }
   .navbar-header { display: inline-block; float: none !important; }
   .navbar-collapse.collapse { display: inline-block !important; }
}
```

Here is solution on: http://jsfiddle.net/myN2s/ .

Let me know if you solve this.

Everytime when you want to center elements, you need to add `text-align:center` to the parent element, and `display: inline-block` to elements which you want to center horizontally. None of these can be **floated** (this is very important).

Comment: Well it seems like this works for big screens, `navbar-header navbar-collapse.collapse` breaks collapsing for small screens.

Answer (score 1):

This fix wil affect all styles on your page. But I guess it is what you are asking for, there was not enough space to put in on one line.
http://jsfiddle.net/mcqHE/58/

```
* {
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the below answer covered most of it, I noticed the menus are still not in one-line, here are the following change I've made:

1) Yes, it's the width that's creating the two-gaps but the major culprit is the `.container`. So remove the `<div>` with the class `.container`

2) Add this CSS to keep your menu items centered:

```
.navbar-inner { text-align: center; }
```

3) Lastly this:

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse.in{ display: inline-block !important; }
```

Binds the two `<ul>` elements together.

#### Additional:

If you want the heading 'Navbar' to be centered too, you can do:

```
.navbar-header { float: none; }
```

Here's the **[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DVtVm/)**

And it's **[effect](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//jsfiddle.net/DVtVm/embedded/result/&w=1600&h=1080)** on a resolution > 1350px.

Comment: It seems like this doesn't work for small screens. It works for 1350px+

Comment: @trante Understood what you meant, the css selector was targeting the `navbar collapse` both on open and close, made the change and this is how it [looks.](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//jsfiddle.net/99CRu/1/embedded/result&w=320&h=568&a=37)

Comment: Well, I don't prefer to "Navbar" text to be centered. Because in that case a new line appears, and it makes navbar height bigger :)

Answer (score 1):

for navbar 1 add the following css to this div div class="navbar-collapse navbar-part2 collapse

```
max-width: 1350px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

max width will make sure the nav part wont go wider than 1350px
margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto will center the nav.

I think this is what you're after? if not sorry!